# White/blank screen after run cordova app on windows, but in browser all is OK

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I create example cordova app template, implementing my code in **www** dir, run in browser Chrome, Edge, Firefox and all is ok.

```
cordova run browser
```

[image]

But if I execute

```
cordova run windows
```

Project builds succesfully but I see only white/blank screen and nothing else

[image]
[image]

Same problem on android build

There is my config

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
    <engine name="windows" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

Where is the problem? No errors, no debug info

Answer (score 2):

If there are no errors in the console, you likely aren't removing your splash screen in your `config.xml` file like so

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

Or after the `deviceReady` event, you can do it yourself with the [cordova-splash plugin](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash).

Comment: thanx for suggestion, but it's not because of splashcreen, I try some variants - same result

Comment: @s4urp8n take a look at this then and see if this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935021/how-to-define-content-security-policy-in-cordova-properly

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

1. Remove your `cordova.js` tag from top (it's neither in the head nor inside body) and put the following code just before the `</body>` tag (just before closing body tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
```

2. Remove all three `engine` specs from your config.xml.