# White blank screen issue with cordova ios with cordova-plugin-ionic-webview or cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugins

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, wkwebview

There will an issue with UIWebview in ios. Apple is going to reject app using this. So we decided to use WKWebview for our cordova ios app. I installed cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine and added `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />` in config.xml file. 
The issue is after the splash screen Its showing white blank screen.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.1.3" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~5.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="^0.7.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="^0.8.8" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.7.2" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: how to solve this issue? I have added the plugins but still their issue.
how can I get this solve? I am using PhoneGap.

Comment: any news ? still have problem with that, I tried everything in this page

Answer (score 12):

remember to add this plugins:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine"  source="npm" /> 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr"  source="npm" />
```

and add this

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" value="true" />
<preference name="Allow3DTouchLinkPreview" value="false" />
```

compile with cordova-ios@5.1.1

---

*To build it with cordova-ios@6.1.0+*

- remove splash plugin (now is integrated)
- upgrade the inappbrowser plugin to v4.0.0
- remove all wkwebview related plugins
- add scheme and host to config.xml:

```
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost"  />
```

Comment: how to solve this issue? I have added the plugins but still their issue.
how can I get this solve? I am using PhoneGap.

Comment: Nowadays I've migrated to cordova-ios@6.1.0 to compile without issues, keep in mind that in v6.1.0 you should:  remove splash plugin, upgrade the inappbrowser plugin to v4.0.0,   remove all wkwebview related plugins, add scheme and host to config.xml:
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />.    PGB for IOS is no longer maintained :(

Comment: hi @VeroO, I still have this issue after all update, can you give more info about the scheme and host, is it something new from cordova-ios@6.1.0. Even using Xcode we still need localhost? Then what we need to set there for appstore version? Btw, I think the splash plugin is still required for Android, there is a new version 5.0.4 for it to bypass iOS.

Comment: Hi @HuyVu, for Android you can still use PGB, but for ios no. Take a look at this cheatsheet I've created:  https://medium.com/@vosorio/build-ios-ipa-from-cordova-command-line-80f3e1794e0

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I had to reinstall ios platform to make it work (to version 5.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

According to cordova documentation :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/blob/master/README.md

Correct way to do it: 
https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/?utm_campaign=enterprise&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=85128961&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--vsf3kcg7MssMWwjv2_GpHmVbzN23_5fXDfKT0E6OileYraLWs9btGPqWUcq5mzTKCtKwXGqO35V3SnInjypj4uqSBRg&_hsmi=85128961

These permissions have to be added

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /> 
</feature> 
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

So check they are added plus as the documentation say:
"In iOS 9, Apple has fixed the issuepresent through iOS 8 where you cannot load locale files using file://, and must resort to using a local webserver. However, you are still not able to use XHR from the file:// protocol without CORS enabled on your server."

So if your testing on a version 8 then there is problem but i think as i saw the implementation is still not full in your config.xml so update it with the feature and preference.

Comment: I added those lines in config.xml file. Still same white screen issue

Comment: Ok if you inspect the app when white screen appears? Do any error apear in the console?

Comment: You still have cordova-plugin-ionic-webview , it should be removed since the new plugin is installed

Comment: I removed it and installed 'cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine'. Then prepare ios and build ios. Same white screen result.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/?utm_campaign=enterprise&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=85128961&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--vsf3kcg7MssMWwjv2_GpHmVbzN23_5fXDfKT0E6OileYraLWs9btGPqWUcq5mzTKCtKwXGqO35V3SnInjypj4uqSBRg&_hsmi=85128961

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is not actually a white screen but a blank view with a white background, the cordova app is not rendering properly and if you scroll you can see all the div views below.

This appears to be an issue with cordova apps on the new iOS 13.4 release, regardless of using UIWebview or WKWebview.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. I have build the app after making changes in config.xml by adding line <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>.  After the build, the app just show white screen. Could you please suggest how to resolve the issue. Thank You

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue? The deadline to upgrade to WKWebView is coming up in December and upgrading caused this issue for me as well.

Comment: I switched to the ionic webview plugin and set the wkwebview only preference in the config.xml

Comment: how to solve this issue? I have added the plugins but still their issue.
how can I get this solve? I am using PhoneGap.

Comment: It's also an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `tsconfig.json` and make sure in `compilerOptions` the `target` is set to `es5`. I tried all and only this works for me

Answer (score 0):

The only 1 working package as of today to solve the issue is https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix (nothing apart installation is needed.

Other packages cause `CDVPlugin class WKWebViewXHRFix (pluginName: wkwebviewxhrfix)`.